# JPA application not getting deployed in Cloud Foundary - IBM Bluemix

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have created JPA Spring boot application which is working properly in my local environment, however, while deploying it to **Java Liberty** Cloud Foundary app in IBM Bluemix with following error:

Local IDE: `Eclipse Oxygen` 
when I run this application on my local IDE, it accessed cloud Db Compose for MySQL and give result as expected.
http://localhost:8080/users/all

Deployment in IBM Bluemix, it's  give an error message
    Server: `IBM Bluemix`
    Deployment: `Cloud Foundary`
    Cloud Foundary App: `Java Liberty` 
    DataBase : `Compose for MySQL`

Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /

```
pom.xml

<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**messages.log**

```
[9/15/17 9:59:23:464 UTC] 00000026 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/state/plugin-cfg.xml.
[9/15/17 9:59:23:990 UTC] 00000033 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields 249" at ffdc_17.09.15_09.59.23.0.log
[9/15/17 9:59:24:002 UTC] 00000033 com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager         W CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver
[9/15/17 9:59:24:020 UTC] 00000033 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap.getAllDeclaredMethods 106" at ffdc_17.09.15_09.59.24.0.log
[9/15/17 9:59:24:021 UTC] 00000033 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap                      W CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver
```

**ffdc_17.09.15_09.59.23.0.log**

```
Exception = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Source = com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields
probeid = 249
Stack Dump = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessorManager.java:375)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.processAnnotations(InjectionProcessorManager.java:216)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:514)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.java:239)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(ReferenceContextImpl.java:595)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:290)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiReferenceContextImpl.process(OSGiReferenceContextImpl.java:31)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(WebApp.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1039)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6595)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1120)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:104)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:932)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:282)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: When running locally was it on Tomcat or was that also on Liberty?

Comment: Spring Boot > run as Java Application.

Comment: problem resolved. Configured manifest file as per your application binding services. push manifest file